# Catch-up problems in Rate, Time, Distance (RTD) category.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

> Car-X is $40$-miles West of Car-Y. Both cars are traveling East, and Car-$X$ is going $50$% faster than Car-$Y$. If both cars travel at a constant rate, and it takes Car-$X$ $2$ hours and $40$ minutes to catch up to Car-$Y$, how fast was the Car-$Y$ going?

This problem can be solved by using the so-called $(A-B)$ technique as follows:

> $1.5r-r = 0.5r$
>
> So,  $0.5r \times \frac{8}{3} = 40$
>   $\implies r = 30$

.

Can the **following** problem be solved using the **above** technique?

> Scott starts jogging from point-$X$ to point-$Y$. A half-hour later his friend Garrett who jogs $1$ mile per hour slower than twice Scott's rate, starts from the same point and follows the same path. If Garrett overtakes Scott in $2$ hours, how many miles will Garrett have covered?

If No, why not?

Comment: Did you mean to write $\frac{8}{3}$ rather than $83$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, oh, yes!!!!!!

Comment: I am guessing you also meant to write Car-X is $40$ miles west of Car-Y.  The most obvious difference between the two problems is that in the first problem, the two cars are starting at the same time, which is not the case in the second problem.  You have to account for this by using $r/2$ as the distance between Scott and Garrett when Garrett starts jogging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same approach

Let us take Garrett's rate $=(2x-1)$ mph and

Scott's rate $=x$ mph

Since both are walking in same direction, speed$=2x-1=x-1$

The formula for relative distance between Garrett and Scott $=$ distance covered by Scott in initial half an hour which is $=\frac x2$

Now,
$$\frac x2=(x-1)2$$
$$x=4x-4$$
$$x=\frac43mph$$

The number of miles covered by Garrett in $2$ hours is $=(2(\frac43)-1)2=\frac{10}{3}$miles

Comment: The obvious difference is, in the latter case, we have to calculate both *Scott* and *Garrett*.

Comment: Yes, you can also calculate Scott

Comment: `can` or `must`?

Comment: can you solve the problem without solving for *Scott*?

Comment: @yahoo.com I mean we cannot. See the equations which I have taken in the answer. We get the Garatte distance only after solving for $x$ which is Scott

Comment: Technically you can solve the problem without ever writing the number $\frac43,$ that is, it is not _really_ necessary to solve for Scott's speed--but solving for Scott's speed (as shown in the answer above) is a natural way to attack the problem and (I think) very likely the easiest. You _can_ solve the problem without finding Scott's speed, but _should_ you?

Comment: This answer has typo? $2x-1=x-1 \iff x = 0$. But $x$ is NOT 0 here!

Answer (score 0):

Let Garrett's speed be $v$ miles per hour.

Scott's speed is half of a speed that is $1$ mph faster than Garrett's,
that is, Scott's speed is $\frac12(v + 1).$

The rate at which Garrett closes the distance to Scott (after Garrett starts running) is $ v - \frac12(v + 1) = \frac12(v - 1).$

In $\frac12$ hour, Scott covers the same distance at rate $\frac12(v + 1)$
that Garrett is able to close in $2$ hours at rate $\frac12(v - 1)$.
That is,
$$
\frac12\left(\frac12(v + 1)\right) = 2\left(\frac12(v - 1)\right).
$$
Simplifying,
$$ \frac14(v + 1) = v - 1, $$
$$ \frac54 = \frac34v, $$
$$ v = \frac53.$$

So in $2$ hours, the distance Garrett covers is
$$ 2 \left(\frac53\right) = \frac{10}{3}. $$

This is not a better solution than the other way;
I just wanted to demonstrate that it is not necessary to
solve for Scott's speed explicitly.
With a little more effort we could avoid explicitly solving for Garrett's speed as well!

Comment: Just to be clear, I think the other answer is an easier (therefore better) approach. (That's why I mentioned it would take even _more_ effort to compute _fewer_ of the unknown quantities.) Avoiding the computation of unasked-for results is not always a virtue!